# Quickest way to increment counter in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, percona

I'm running a forum on a VPS, running Percona DB, with PHP 5.5.8, Opcode caching, etc, it's all very speed orientated.

I'm also running New Relic, (yes I have the t-shirt).

As I'm tuning the application, optimising queries the forum is making to the DB for any query at the top of my time consumed list.

Right now, the most time consuming query I have, as it's the most frequently used is a simple hit counter on each topic.

So the query is:

```
UPDATE topics SET num_views = num_views + 1  WHERE id_topic = ?
```

I can't think of a simpler way to perform this, or if any of the various other ways might be quicker, and why.

Is there a way of writing this query to be even faster, or an index I can add to a field to aide speed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `id_topic` is indexed, you're not going to get better.   The only recommendation I would have is to look at the other indexes on this table and make sure you don't have redundant ones that include `num_views` in them.  That would decrease update speed on this update.

For example if you had the following indexes

1. ( some_column, num_views)
2. ( some_column, num_views, another_column)

Index #1 would be extraneous and just add to the insert/update overhead

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I didn't think it could be made quicker, but I thought possibly applying something like LIMIT = 1 (even though there would only ever be one id_topic) might improve it's speed if internally that makes it's "WHERE" clause take less time.

In addition, your mentioning of indexes made me look at the indexes, and there's 8 indexes, some duplicate and none on the id_topic field! So thanks for unearthing that issue for me! :)

Comment: @i-CONICA if the id_topic is a unique index (like primary key) adding a limit after the where would not help.  If it's not unique, I'd be confused with how you're looking up with it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is an improvement, but you could check the following:

How about only adding a row for each page hit to the table instead of locking and updating the row?

And then using a count to get the results, and cache them instead of doing the count each time?

(And maybe compacting the table once per day?)